# What if connection is lost when I am consuming web service in mobile device

Tags: c#, ios, rest, xamarin.ios

I got one question. I am going to use RESTfull web service in my mobile app(which is based on C#, monotouch). I have to send big data using either json or xml. Can I make sure that in case connection is lost I want to stop pulling data and cancel rest of the data which has been pulled.

Basically. my target is that I don't want to pull partially. I need whole data without loosing it.

Any other idea how can I achieve this?

Just wanted to ask another question. How can I secure my url which refer to data. If I use RESTfull webservice

Comment: e.g if half of the data has been sent. in another side will I receive half or I dont' get anything

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSURLConnection as follows

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]] delegate:self];
```

Then, you can use the following two delegate methods to check if the data downloaded fully.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //Download failed
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //Download success
}
```